# customized bootstrap doesn't contain less file

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, less

I am customizing the bootstrap using this link http://getbootstrap.com/customize/. When I download there is no LESS file, only CSS files inside the customized bootstrap. How can I get the customized  bootstrap with LESS files.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need customized less files. When you use the less version of bootstrap, you can have a look at bootstrap.less - it imports all the different components. 
In your custom less file, you can just import the ones you need instead of bootstrap/bootstrap.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could start using [bower](http://bower.io/) to organize all your dependencies. Tried installing it and run `bower install bootstrap` and all the files will be automatically downloaded into `bower_components/bootstrap` folder. The sources included all the less files per components.

Comment: This will download  the default bootstrap. I want the customized bootstrap. I want to change my grid gutter width and grid width.

Comment: you can add a variable.less and specify `@grid-gutter-width` and `@grid-width` to override the default value